# How to move a view inside a custom cell, by modifying the Top constant of its constraint?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

I would like to make a view scroll down by changing the *constant* of its Top constraint. The view is inside a custom `UITableViewCell` and I linked the constraint from a `.xib` with an `IBOutlet`.

From there, in my controller, when we scroll the tableview, the view in the cell should go down, regarding the `contentOffset` : I divide the `contentOffset` by the height of a cell to select the cell with its index , and I try to change the constraint of my view in this cell. (I tried row+1, or row+2 to see the changes, but nothing happens).

**The problem is**: if I scroll, nothing happens, the view in the cell does not scroll.
If I scroll down, and come back, then the view has scrolled to the bottom of the cell.  Maybe the problem is when the cell is "visible"? I tried `layoutIfNeeded()` just in case, but it does nothing.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(p_scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if p_scrollView == tableView {
        let row = Int(CGFloat(p_scrollView.contentOffset.y) / CGFloat(heightCell))
        let ratioScroll = CGFloat(p_scrollView.contentOffset.y) / CGFloat(heightCell)
        //row 5, scroll 5.32 -> 5.32 - 5 = 0.32 -> (0.32 * 44) - 44 => value between [-44, 0]
        let decimalOnly = ratioScroll - CGFloat(row)
        println("decimalOnly : \(decimalOnly)") //betwwen [0,1]

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row+3, inSection: 0)) as MyCell
        let scrollY : CGFloat = (CGFloat(decimalOnly) * CGFloat(heightCell)) - CGFloat(heightCell)

        cell.constraintTopViewAbove = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.viewAbove, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: scrollY)
        //cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        //cell.setNeedsDisplay()



//my custom cell :        
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var viewAbove: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var constraintTopViewAbove: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

The `.xib` of my custom cell, with the `IBOutlet` on vertical Spacing constraint : at the beginning, the view ("viewAbove", the green rectangle) is at `-44` to hide it. Then, I want to scroll it between [-44, 0] :

[image]

---

EDIT:

[image]

Then, when I scroll down, and up again, the cells are dequeued :

[image]

```
println("constant row \(row) : \(cell0.constraintTopViewAbove.constant)")
println("constant row \(row+1) : \(cell.constraintTopViewAbove.constant)")
```

Comment: you assign a new `NSLayoutConstraint` to cell's constraintTopViewAbove, overwrite the xib ref one. you can change the `cell.constraintTopViewAbove.constant` to the value you want. and then call  `cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints` to make update valid.

Comment: @SolaWing Great thanks, if you post it as an answer I will accept it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @SolaWing one question though, when a cell disappear after a scroll, the viewAbove (the green rectangle) will overlay the whole cell after it is dequeued again (when we scroll down, then up again). It does not do it when the cell is still visible, the green rectangle stays behind the text. There is a change when the cell, I think, is dequeued. Would you know how to debug this? The constant works fine though, the log tells me exactly what I expect : the constant goes up or down when we scroll.

Comment: when cell disappear and redequeued, tableView reuse previous cell and keep the previous state. you need to init cell's related values to default. also. for example, reset constraint'sconstant to initial value

Comment: Thanks @SolaWing , I edited my post with some images. The logs are correct: when the top constant of row 1 is changing, the log shows it (it goes from 0 to -44 as expected), but the green rectangle stays as is. And, it now hides the content of the cell (the text is always in front of the green rectangle, now it is the green rectangle that stays in front...) So your solution: reset the constant : the log already shows the right constant...

Comment: I think the reason is: the green bar at top of cell has a higher z order and overlay the other cell of lower z order. you can select `Clip Subviews` Option to limit the green bar's view size in it's own cell.

Comment: Thanks @SolaWing, I don't know, there is still this bug. I will maybe come back later on this... If by any chance, you could try it on a new project :) otherwise, thanks again for the support.

Comment: Other reason I can thought: your layout constrain is not fully restrict, you limit the top space, but the view still have variable height. the variability can cause various layout problem.